# Using external assembly's method's results as a dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Using SQL2008R2:
I am trying to create a dataset that is simply the result of an external assembly's return method(s), but everything I can find regarding using custom/external assemblies just has a textbox's value set to the external assembly's method's result via an expression.

I simply want Report Server to do the data processing in the external assembly and bind that result to a very simple report.

I found some references to something about MDX but they seem to be a few years outdated and needed to know if this is possible.

Comment: To clarify, I know I can set an XML datasource to a webservice. In this case, I want the report server to do the work and not the web server.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already have a .dll - Place your dll in the report designer folder (where your RDL is) and the report server folder, somewhere around here:

```
Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin
```

Now add a reference to your dll from your report.
With your report open go to Report, Report Properties, References, Add reference, browse to your dll and add it.

Now in a text box properties Value call a method of your dll.  It should look something like this:

```
=MyDllName.ClassName.MyMethodOrSubOrWhatever
```

This is a great article that can walk you through this:

Assuming you already have a .dll - Place your dll in the report designer folder (where your RDL is) and the report server folder, somewhere around here:

Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin

Now add a reference to your dll from your report.
With your report open go to Report, Report Properties, References, Add reference, browse to your dll and add it.

Now in a text box properties Value call a method of your dll.  It should look something like this:
=MyDllName.ClassName.MyMethodOrSubOrWhatever

This is a great article that can walk you through this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920769

P.S. Another option, if you don't want the web server doing the heavy lifting, is to use stored procedures. However, in our experience with very large database systems, it is much easier to scale up the web servers than it is to scale up the database servers so we do much of the heavy lifting on the web servers.

Comment: thanks but I wanted to have the method result of the external assembly as a dataset, not point a textbox to a piece of data. The method in the assembly returns a dataset. And doing a stored procedure would require using CLR stuff on the database so it can use our businesslayer to do the compliation, which is certainly an option but we wanted to explore some other options.

Comment: I don't have an assembly to test with, but I would try Add New Dataset > Query type: Text > Function > =MyAssmbly.Etc.. The data should pass parameters and expect a data table back.  Now I want to know so as soon as I have some spare time I'm going to toss together a test  :) I guess the function would have to call the assembly with command line parameters such as /myDllParamFoo = @myRdlParamFoo /myDllNextParam = myNextRdlParam

Comment: This question is about using the data returned by the assembly as a _data set_, not as query text

Answer (score 2):

If you need a data set that is generated by custom .NET code, you can either set up a web service ([here's a good tutorial](http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/webservice-as-datasource-in-ssrs/)), or you can set up a custom "data processing extension".

A data processing extension will allow you to choose a new data source in the SSRS report designer, and this data source will run custom .NET code. The [full description](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154655.aspx) is on MSDN, but here are the basic steps:

1. Create a new class library project
2. Implement all of the required extensions (and any desired optional ones)
3. Copy the DLL to the SSRS `bin` folder
4. Edit the SSRS config file to register your extension (by specifying the fully qualified name of your [`IDbConnection`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.dataprocessing.idbconnection.aspx) class)

You can find working examples from both [CodePlex](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22946/Implementing-a-Data-Processing-Extension) and [Microsoft](http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2008%21File%20Share%20Data%20Processing%20Extension%20Sample&referringTitle=Home).